# MVC .Net MultiSelectList does not mark values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple problem, that I don't have with SelectList!
I just wan't to pre-select entries in MultiSelectList and here is my simple code:

```
List<Language> lLang = new List<Language>
        {
            new Language { Abbreviation = "DE", Name = "German" },
            new Language { Abbreviation = "IT", Name = "Italian" }
        };

ViewBag.Languages = new MultiSelectList(lLang, "Abbreviation", "Name", new string[] { "DE", "IT" });
```

In order that you see, that the values are actually correct, here the rendered HTML code:

```
<select id="Languages" name="Languages" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="AF"> … </option>
    <option value="AR"> … </option>
    <option value="DA"> … </option>
    <option value="DE"> … </option>
</select>
```

As you see, the option value "DE" is not selected!

Any ideas?!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the View's part where you are displaying the list?

Comment: Problem solved.
I removed "ViewBag.Languages as MultiSelectLis" in 


<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.ListBox("Languages", ViewBag.Languages as MultiSelectList)
</div>